# Can we use AdviceWith for non testing purpose?

Tags: java, apache-camel

We have scenario where we deliver our Camel application as jar to customer, and allow customer to create customisations to it, in some scenarios they might want to replace node in camel route,

Is it advisable to use AdviceWith in this scenario, or is its use only meant for testing?

I was able to use AdviceWith to replace route for non-testing purpose by extending EventNotifierSupport's notify method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advice with is only intended for testing. And its feature and design is for testing purposes only.

However you can of course do anything you like with Camel.

Maybe what you want to do can be archived in another way, as advice with is using existing functionality in the camel-api that you could look at using directly also.

Comment: Ok thanks, for a short term I will go ahead with AdviceWith and for long term reliable solution, digging into implementation of AdviceWith is better